# Spring MVC Multi module Property Source failure

Tags: spring, maven, properties, spring-test, multi-module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQCp.png)SpringMVC with javaconfig PropertySource failed in same module what should I do

code below :

```
@Configuration
@Import(ContextMyBatis.class)
@PropertySource("/properties/datasource.properties")
public class ContextDatabase {
  @Value("${datasource.driverClass}")Class<? extends Driver> driver;
  @Value("${datasource.username}") String user;
  @Value("${datasource.password}") String password;
  @Value("${datasource.url}") String URL;
  [enter image description here][1]....
}
```

Comment: i copied my resource files in target folder and it work how can I solve it ?

Comment: please also add the StackTrace and the code for the test which is failing